# Need help wth error 'Permission denied (publickey,password)'

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

i am trying to ssh to a remote instance and i keep getting `Permission denied (publickey,password)` error. What is weird is that i am able to ssh into instance-01. I have pasted the verbose logs , would be great if someone can tell me what might be going on and how to fix the error. Thanks in advance.

```
[user@ip-20-0-185-76 ~]$ ssh -v instance-02
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/managed_hosts.config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/managed_hosts.config line 7: Applying options for instance-02
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target mi-044f942125677608ef --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=22'"
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/fooci.id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/fooci.id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: Starting session with SessionId: ConduitAccountService+Prod+Default+NA+Fleet+P-foo-0eb45c9b78f1eac7c

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 XXXXXX-10+deb10u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 XXXXXXX-10+deb10u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to instance-02:22 as 'foo'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: xxx-xxx-xxxx SHA256:sbIKHNlNOAxxxxxxx9MCS7PneubylAzBO3yOCfd5/o
debug1: Host 'instance-02' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/fooci.id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Permission of the identity file if relevant

```
[user@ip-20-0-185-76 ~]$ ls -la /home/user/.ssh/fooci.id_rsa
-rw------- 1 user user 1675 Aug  2 22:29 /home/user/.ssh/fooci.id_rsa
```

content of sshd_config file

```
# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#
# Uncomment this if you want to use .local domain
# Host *.local
#   CheckHostIP no

Host *
        GSSAPIAuthentication yes
# If this option is set to yes then remote X11 clients will have full access
# to the original X11 display. As virtually no X11 client supports the untrusted
# mode correctly we set this to yes.
        ForwardX11Trusted yes
# Send locale-related environment variables
        SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
        SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
        SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
        SendEnv XMODIFIERS
```

location and permission of authorized_keys

```
[user@ip-20-0-185-76 ~]$ ls -la

drwxr-xr-x 5 user user  4096 Oct 14 09:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Oct 13 17:41 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  4428 Aug  2 22:28 authorized_keys
```

Comment: do u have a user name is `user` on `instance-02` server? do u add your ssh key to `.ssh/authorized_keys`? also pls post your sshd_config on both server.

Comment: user was just a dummy name , actually it is something else. Added ssd_config on the machine used for ssh.

Comment: `sshd_config` on server, not `ssh_config`, sshd for server side config, ssh for client side config. as you say, pls check the user exist in `instance-02`, and your ssh-key public key exist in remote user home `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: and, i see your ssh key type is rsa, check [openssh release note 8.7](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7), it says `OpenSSH will disable the ssh-rsa signature scheme by default in the
next release.`. pls check your openssh version, and if over 8.7, try add `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa` line to server `sshd_config`